# Gradient ascent, log likelihood

Tags: probability, optimization

Good day, hi, would like to ask a question. If you have some spare time please kindly enlighten me on the following question.

Gradient ascent: $=\sigma \leftarrow \sigma + \dfrac{d}{d\sigma} p(y\mid x,\sigma)$

Does the equation hold for the case of log likelihood?

$$\sigma \leftarrow \sigma + \frac{d}{d\sigma} \log (p(y\mid x,\sigma))$$

Thanks a million in advance for your forthcoming response!!

Comment: its related to Boltzmann Machine learning problem.

Answer (score 2):

lol, found this gem, after searching longer -**_**-.
ans: yes, pg11 of http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/250B/logreg.pdf